# Calculate sum of records in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server and what I want to do is select a Distinct BankName, BankMonth and BankYear and then also select the most recent and unique BankWeek i.e Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4 for each BankName. So basically four records are going to be returned per bank. Once they are returned, I want to sum each of their RevenueCodeTotal value and update a column in the table with that value.

This is an image of the sample table:

[image]

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  What have you tried?  Why didnt it work?  Check into Group By.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` for filtering and then aggregate:

```
select bankname, sum(revenuecodetotal)
from (select t.*
             row_number() over (partition by BankName, BankMonth, BankYear order by bankweek desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by bankname;
```